# Is there one word that means ' an exaggerated action'?

Tags: synonyms

ex. I falcon punch him so hard he woke up back in daycare.

I'm looking for a word to use in place of 'over the top' in the sentence 'I'm a student of over-the-top Kung Fu.'

Comment: Look up *overkill*

Comment: exaggerated works

Comment: As JonMark Perry said, what is the problem with the word "exaggerated," which you seem to be already familiar with judging from the title of this question, or its synonyms that you can find listed in a [thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/exaggerated?s=t)? E.g. why can't you just say "I'm a student of over-the-top Kung Fu" or "I'm a student of exaggerated Kung Fu." When you ask for a synonym, you should explain why you want it.

Comment: What's with this ***falcon**?* Is it some kind of eye-dialect / euphemistic version of ***fuckin'**?* There's the relatively recent BrE usage *He drives a big **fuck-off** car*, where that one effectively means *over the top, "in-your-face"*.

Comment: Falcon Punch is a special move by Captain Falcon, a video game character. It became a meme, meaning to punch someone intensely.

Answer (score 2):

None of these are specific to actions, but might work: melodramatic, sensationalist, flamboyant, exaggerated, extreme, outrageous, outlandish, grandiose, excessive, ostentatious, showy.

I'd try just clicking around on thesaurus.com to see what appeals to you.

Answer (score -3):

I think that AlannaRose's answers are good but if you are looking for a word that means an action, and bearing in mind that "xyz Fu" is used to refer to the art of xyz then 
 'I'm a student of Pose Fu.'
 'I'm a student of Posturing Fu.'
or combined with AlannaRose's suggestion, things like
 'I'm a student of Flamboyant Fu,' or
 'I'm a student of Flamboyance Fu.'
It is a shame there is not a word meaning posturing/flamboyant beginning with K. The closest I can think of is
 'I'm a student of Kamp Fu.' 
but is misspelt, and gay.

Comment: We're looking for answers written at an expert level, and we also aim for a respectful tone appropriate to a professional or collegiate community.